# Desirable result in "UNION"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

MY sql query is

```
SELECT id, content FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT p_id, p_content FROM table2;
```

It is giving the desirable result but with column name of first select statement.

e.g

if the query get the data from second select statement it give the result as

```
array (size=2)
  'id' => string '15' (length=2)
  'content' => string 'table2 content' (length=22)
```

i want column name with respective select statement result.

e.g

if select got result from first select then the array of result should be like this

```
array (size=2)
  'id' => string '15' (length=2)
  'content' => string 'table1 content' (length=22)
```

else if select got result from second select statement then the array of result should be like this

```
array (size=2)
  '**p_id**' => string '15' (length=2)
  '**p_content**' => string 'table2 content' (length=22)
```

Comment: Not possible in one query. Column can have only one name for whole resultset

Comment: cud you give me suggestion ...what should i do in this case, i want same arrary result...

Comment: Why would you need this in the first place? Maybe there's something else to do to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The column names will be the same throughout the query result. Those column names are actually the column names of the query result and don't need to be the same as column names in the table(s):

```
SELECT id as Numbers, content as Texts FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT p_id, p_content FROM table2;
```

You can execute two separate queries and process their results separately.

Or otherwise you could return an extra constant value to determine between the results:

```
SELECT id, content, '1' as TableNr FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT p_id, p_content, '2' FROM table2;
```

Now, for each row you can ask the value of the column 'TableNr' to see which table it came from.